# MATLAB - How do I extract the molecules from an SDF file with an ID in another text file, into a new SDF file?

Tags: matlab, text, extract, bioinformatics, sdf

I have an SDF file with thousands of molecules and several text files of ID's grouped together by certain characteristics. Right now, I have a script that loads in an CSV database with the features of the molecules and generates the ID text files by classifying based on these features. I want to use these text files to parse the SDF file to get new SDF files with the corresponding molecules. In addition, I want to do this in MATLAB.

For example, here are some molecules in the original SDF file:

```
NCGC00178831-03
  Marvin  07111412562D          

 34 37  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
    4.8814   -2.7443    0.0000 Cl  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8647   -2.4751    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8647   -1.6501    0.0000 N   0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5808   -1.2318    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2970   -1.6501    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0017   -1.2318    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7179   -1.6501    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0017   -0.4068    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2970    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5808   -0.4068    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8647    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1485   -0.4068    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1485   -1.2318    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4324   -1.6501    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7162   -1.2318    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -1.6501    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7162   -0.4068    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4324    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8761   -3.5407    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5923   -3.9590    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3084   -3.5407    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0132   -3.9590    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7293   -3.5407    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0132   -4.7840    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3084   -5.1908    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5923   -4.7840    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8761   -5.1908    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1599   -4.7840    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1599   -3.9590    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4438   -3.5407    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7276   -3.9590    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0115   -3.5407    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7276   -4.7840    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4438   -5.1908    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  2  0  0  0  0
  3 13  1  0  0  0  0
  4  5  1  0  0  0  0
  4 10  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  2  0  0  0  0
  6  7  1  0  0  0  0
  6  8  1  0  0  0  0
  8  9  2  0  0  0  0
  9 10  1  0  0  0  0
 10 11  2  0  0  0  0
 11 12  1  0  0  0  0
 12 13  2  0  0  0  0
 12 18  1  0  0  0  0
 13 14  1  0  0  0  0
 14 15  2  0  0  0  0
 15 16  1  0  0  0  0
 15 17  1  0  0  0  0
 17 18  2  0  0  0  0
 19 20  2  0  0  0  0
 19 29  1  0  0  0  0
 20 21  1  0  0  0  0
 20 26  1  0  0  0  0
 21 22  2  0  0  0  0
 22 23  1  0  0  0  0
 22 24  1  0  0  0  0
 24 25  2  0  0  0  0
 25 26  1  0  0  0  0
 26 27  2  0  0  0  0
 27 28  1  0  0  0  0
 28 29  2  0  0  0  0
 28 34  1  0  0  0  0
 29 30  1  0  0  0  0
 30 31  2  0  0  0  0
 31 32  1  0  0  0  0
 31 33  1  0  0  0  0
 33 34  2  0  0  0  0
M  CHG  2   1  -1   3   1
M  END
>  <Formula>
C27H25ClN6

>  <FW>
468.9806 (35.4535+224.2805+209.2465)

>  <DSSTox_CID>
25848

>  <SR-HSE>
0

$$$$
NCGC00166114-03
  Marvin  07111412562D          

 31 32  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
    4.9884   -1.2417    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.9884   -2.0696    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2748   -2.4764    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2748   -3.7038    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.9884   -4.1178    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7021   -3.7038    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.4157   -4.1178    0.0000 O   0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7021   -2.8760    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.9884   -4.9385    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2748   -5.3524    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5612   -4.9385    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5612   -4.1178    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5612   -2.0696    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5612   -1.2417    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2748   -0.8279    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8403   -0.8279    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1267   -1.2417    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1267   -2.0696    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8403   -2.4764    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4202   -2.4764    0.0000 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4202   -0.8279    0.0000 O   0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8403    0.0000    0.0000 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7021   -2.4764    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.4229   -2.0696    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.4229   -1.2417    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7021   -0.8279    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7021    0.0000    0.0000 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.1366   -0.8279    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.1366   -2.4764    0.0000 Br  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0866   -4.1963    0.0000 Na  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -0.7708    0.0000 Na  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
  1 15  1  0  0  0  0
  1 26  2  0  0  0  0
  2  3  2  0  0  0  0
  2 23  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  1  0  0  0  0
  3 13  1  0  0  0  0
  4  5  2  0  0  0  0
  4 12  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  1  0  0  0  0
  5  9  1  0  0  0  0
  6  7  1  0  0  0  0
  6  8  2  0  0  0  0
  9 10  2  0  0  0  0
 10 11  1  0  0  0  0
 11 12  2  0  0  0  0
 13 14  2  0  0  0  0
 13 19  1  0  0  0  0
 14 15  1  0  0  0  0
 14 16  1  0  0  0  0
 16 17  2  0  0  0  0
 16 22  1  0  0  0  0
 17 18  1  0  0  0  0
 17 21  1  0  0  0  0
 18 19  2  0  0  0  0
 18 20  1  0  0  0  0
 23 24  2  0  0  0  0
 24 25  1  0  0  0  0
 24 29  1  0  0  0  0
 25 26  1  0  0  0  0
 25 28  2  0  0  0  0
 26 27  1  0  0  0  0
M  CHG  4   7  -1  21  -1  30   1  31   1
M  END
>  <Formula>
C20H6Br4Na2O5

>  <FW>
691.8542 (645.8757+22.9892+22.9892)

>  <DSSTox_CID>
5234

>  <SR-HSE>
0

$$$$
NCGC00263563-01
  Marvin  07111412562D          

 71 76  0  0  1  0            999 V2000
    2.1953   -4.9878    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6803   -4.9878    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.9701   -5.4074    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.5858   -4.9878    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.1008   -4.9878    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1953   -4.1484    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.8157   -5.6335    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.1239   -5.8755    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.0893   -5.1008    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6803   -4.1484    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   10.2015   -5.1008    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.5905   -5.1653    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.9633   -5.8755    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3905   -5.4074    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.8755   -5.4074    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.9701   -3.6803    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.4606   -4.3905    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.6558   -5.1653    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    9.5559   -5.5043    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.2476   -5.5043    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.1008   -4.1484    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4850   -5.4074    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.8157   -2.4858    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.9578   -4.9878    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.5858   -4.1484    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.5905   -2.9055    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.3483   -4.3905    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.8157   -1.6626    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.8755   -3.6803    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.3008   -1.6626    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.5905   -1.2429    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.3008   -2.4858    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.8457   -4.9878    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.4606   -3.1961    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.1239   -4.5035    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7748   -4.9878    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.4314   -5.2137    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.9633   -4.5035    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    9.9756   -4.2776    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -5.4074    0.0000 O   0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.6673   -4.2776    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1953   -5.7464    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.8764   -4.2776    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    9.0877   -4.2776    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7748   -4.1484    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.5437   -6.4567    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6803   -3.3736    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.9701   -2.9055    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.8755   -2.9055    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.0110   -1.2429    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.5905   -0.4197    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4850   -3.6803    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.5444   -6.4082    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   10.5566   -4.3905    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3905   -6.1177    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.5035   -3.7933    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.1838   -4.2776    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.0110   -2.9055    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.6558   -3.7449    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   16.1416   -5.2137    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2130   -2.9701    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1953   -2.3729    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.7858   -1.6626    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.3008    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   11.0893   -5.8755    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   12.5905   -5.9885    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.8941   -5.7464    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6803   -5.7464    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.1008   -5.7464    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.6558   -5.9885    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4681   -6.7634    0.0000 N   0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  3  1  0  0  0  0
  1  6  1  0  0  0  0
  1 22  1  6  0  0  0
  1 42  1  1  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0  0
  2 14  1  0  0  0  0
  2 68  1  1  0  0  0
  2 10  1  0  0  0  0
  4 15  1  0  0  0  0
  4 20  1  1  0  0  0
  4 43  1  0  0  0  0
  4 25  1  0  0  0  0
  5 14  1  0  0  0  0
  5 15  1  0  0  0  0
  5 21  1  0  0  0  0
  5 69  1  1  0  0  0
  6 16  1  0  0  0  0
  6 52  1  1  0  0  0
  7  9  1  0  0  0  0
  7 12  1  0  0  0  0
  8 18  1  0  0  0  0
  8 13  1  0  0  0  0
  9 11  1  0  0  0  0
  9 17  1  0  0  0  0
  9 65  1  6  0  0  0
 10 16  1  0  0  0  0
 10 47  1  1  0  0  0
 11 19  1  0  0  0  0
 11 54  1  6  0  0  0
 11 39  1  0  0  0  0
 12 18  1  0  0  0  0
 12 66  1  1  0  0  0
 12 27  1  0  0  0  0
 13 46  1  1  0  0  0
 13 53  1  6  0  0  0
 13 37  1  0  0  0  0
 14 55  1  1  0  0  0
 16 48  1  6  0  0  0
 17 27  1  0  0  0  0
 17 34  1  1  0  0  0
 18 35  1  0  0  0  0
 18 70  1  1  0  0  0
 19 33  1  0  0  0  0
 20 24  1  0  0  0  0
 21 29  1  0  0  0  0
 21 56  1  6  0  0  0
 22 36  1  0  0  0  0
 23 34  1  0  0  0  0
 23 26  1  0  0  0  0
 23 28  1  0  0  0  0
 24 33  1  0  0  0  0
 24 57  1  6  0  0  0
 24 41  1  0  0  0  0
 25 29  1  0  0  0  0
 26 32  1  0  0  0  0
 28 31  1  0  0  0  0
 29 49  1  1  0  0  0
 30 31  1  0  0  0  0
 30 50  1  1  0  0  0
 30 32  1  0  0  0  0
 31 51  1  6  0  0  0
 32 58  1  6  0  0  0
 33 44  1  0  0  0  0
 33 67  1  6  0  0  0
 35 38  1  0  0  0  0
 35 59  1  1  0  0  0
 36 40  1  0  0  0  0
 36 45  2  0  0  0  0
 37 38  1  0  0  0  0
 37 60  1  1  0  0  0
 39 44  1  0  0  0  0
 41 43  1  0  0  0  0
 47 61  1  0  0  0  0
 48 62  1  0  0  0  0
 50 63  1  0  0  0  0
 51 64  1  0  0  0  0
M  CHG  2  40  -1  71   1
M  END
>  <Formula>
C47H83NO17

>  <FW>
934.1584 (916.1205+18.0379)

>  <DSSTox_CID>
28909

>  <SR-HSE>
0

$$$$
```

And here are some ID's from the text file:

```
NCGC00015959-03
NCGC00168261-01
NCGC00257010-01
NCGC00254654-01
NCGC00254471-01
```

The generated SDF file should start like this:

```
NCGC00015959-03
  Marvin  07111412562D          

 25 30  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
    3.4098   -1.3130    0.0000 N   0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.8329   -1.3130    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4098   -2.1380    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.1248   -2.5436    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6948   -2.5436    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.8329   -2.1380    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.1248   -0.8937    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.5547   -0.8937    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.9799   -2.1380    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6948   -3.3548    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.2718   -2.5436    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.2718   -3.3548    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.1248   -3.3548    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.9799   -3.7741    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.5547   -2.5436    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.2765   -1.3130    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7128   -0.0894    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4881   -2.2755    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4881   -3.6160    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.8746   -0.7562    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.5378    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -2.9423    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.4098   -3.7741    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.2765   -2.1380    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.6948   -0.8937    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  3  1  0  0  0  0
  1  7  2  0  0  0  0
  1 25  1  0  0  0  0
  2  7  1  0  0  0  0
  2  6  2  0  0  0  0
  2  8  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  2  0  0  0  0
  3  5  1  0  0  0  0
  4 13  1  0  0  0  0
  4  6  1  0  0  0  0
  5  9  1  0  0  0  0
  5 10  2  0  0  0  0
  6 15  1  0  0  0  0
  8 16  2  0  0  0  0
  8 17  1  0  0  0  0
  9 11  2  0  0  0  0
 10 14  1  0  0  0  0
 10 23  1  0  0  0  0
 11 18  1  0  0  0  0
 11 12  1  0  0  0  0
 12 14  2  0  0  0  0
 12 19  1  0  0  0  0
 13 23  2  0  0  0  0
 15 24  2  0  0  0  0
 16 20  1  0  0  0  0
 16 24  1  0  0  0  0
 17 21  1  0  0  0  0
 18 22  1  0  0  0  0
 19 22  1  0  0  0  0
 20 21  1  0  0  0  0
M  CHG  1   1   1
M  END
>  <Formula>
C20H14NO4

>  <FW>
332.3289

>  <DSSTox_CID>
25204

>  <NR-AR>
0

>  <NR-ER-LBD>
1

>  <NR-AhR>
1

$$$$
NCGC00168261-01
  Marvin  07111412562D          

 23 25  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
    2.1236   -2.4895    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4205   -2.0662    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1236   -3.3074    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4205   -3.7235    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7174   -2.4895    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7174   -3.3074    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8554   -2.0662    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -2.0662    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.4205   -1.2412    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8554   -3.7235    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5656   -2.4895    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.5656   -3.3074    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8554   -1.2412    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7174   -0.8251    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -1.2412    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0430   -2.8984    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7174   -4.1324    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.2902   -3.7378    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7174    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0292   -3.3145    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.4569   -3.3360    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7538   -3.7378    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.1743   -3.7378    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
  1  3  2  0  0  0  0
  1  7  1  0  0  0  0
  2  5  2  0  0  0  0
  2  9  1  0  0  0  0
  3  4  1  0  0  0  0
  3 10  1  0  0  0  0
  4  6  1  0  0  0  0
  5  8  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  1  0  0  0  0
  6 16  1  0  0  0  0
  6 17  1  0  0  0  0
  7 11  2  0  0  0  0
  7 13  1  0  0  0  0
  8 15  2  0  0  0  0
  9 14  2  0  0  0  0
 10 12  2  0  0  0  0
 11 12  1  0  0  0  0
 12 18  1  0  0  0  0
 14 15  1  0  0  0  0
 14 19  1  0  0  0  0
 18 20  1  0  0  0  0
 20 22  1  0  0  0  0
 21 22  1  0  0  0  0
 21 23  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <Formula>
C21H26O2

>  <FW>
310.4299

>  <DSSTox_CID>
28922

>  <NR-AR>
0

>  <NR-AhR>
1

>  <SR-MMP>
1

$$$$
NCGC00257010-01
  Marvin  07111412562D          

 35 37  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
    2.0286   -3.5779    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0019   -7.8578    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0019   -0.7019    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8589   -3.5779    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.6092   -2.8589    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.6092   -4.2799    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.2784   -4.2799    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.5825   -7.1217    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.5825   -1.4381    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.3681   -3.5779    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.5024   -3.5779    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.5024   -4.9989    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.0915   -4.2799    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.3412   -3.5779    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.3412   -4.9989    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7704   -4.2799    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7704   -2.8589    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.7294   -1.1385    0.0000 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.2829   -0.2996    0.0000 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.7294   -7.4213    0.0000 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.4384   -8.5597    0.0000 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.2829   -8.2601    0.0000 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.4384    0.0000    0.0000 F   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0019   -2.1485    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    7.0019   -6.4112    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7607   -1.4381    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7607   -7.1217    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7607   -5.7008    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7607   -2.8589    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.5825   -5.7008    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.5825   -2.8589    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.3412   -6.4112    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.3412   -2.1485    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0000   -2.9103    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.0086   -4.2542    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  4  2  0  0  0  0
  1  5  1  0  0  0  0
  1  6  1  0  0  0  0
  2  8  1  0  0  0  0
  2 20  1  0  0  0  0
  2 21  1  0  0  0  0
  2 22  1  0  0  0  0
  3  9  1  0  0  0  0
  3 18  1  0  0  0  0
  3 19  1  0  0  0  0
  3 23  1  0  0  0  0
  4  7  1  0  0  0  0
  5 17  1  0  0  0  0
  6 16  1  0  0  0  0
  7 13  2  0  0  0  0
  8 27  1  0  0  0  0
  8 25  2  0  0  0  0
  9 26  2  0  0  0  0
  9 24  1  0  0  0  0
 10 16  1  0  0  0  0
 10 34  1  0  0  0  0
 10 35  1  0  0  0  0
 10 17  1  0  0  0  0
 11 13  1  0  0  0  0
 11 14  2  0  0  0  0
 12 13  1  0  0  0  0
 12 15  2  0  0  0  0
 14 29  1  0  0  0  0
 15 28  1  0  0  0  0
 24 31  2  0  0  0  0
 25 30  1  0  0  0  0
 26 33  1  0  0  0  0
 27 32  2  0  0  0  0
 28 30  2  0  0  0  0
 28 32  1  0  0  0  0
 29 31  1  0  0  0  0
 29 33  2  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <Formula>
C25H24F6N4

>  <FW>
494.4753

>  <DSSTox_CID>
3868

>  <NR-AR>
0

>  <NR-ER>
1

>  <NR-AhR>
1

$$$$
```

I've seen this post: [Extract molecules in order from SDF file according to IDs given in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179004/extract-molecules-in-order-from-sdf-file-according-to-ids-given-in-another-file) that offers a solution in unix to solve this. I've used that workaround in the command line:
`awk 'BEGIN{ORS="$$$$"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a' ids.txt RS="$" molecules.sdf > molecules_by_ids.sdf` and was able to get most of what I wanted. However, even when I use this command-line option I am not able to get 100% of the molecules extracted from the SDF file. For example, there are 981 molecules positive for one of the features, the text file gets 981 ID's, and this command gives me 950 molecules in the SDF file.

What I really want is a MATLAB solution that does not miss any of the molecules in the generated file. I appreciate any efforts to make a solution. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, did you try to extract everything from the input file (981 IDs) only to get 950 molecules? There's no reason the awk command you tried shouldn't work unless there are incompatible formatting constraints. It would be helpful to identify and share what fails to be extracted.

Comment: I don't know much about the unix command, but I believe I was using it correctly. I took the command from the answer post and massaged it to my workflow.

To be honest, the 'awk' command works very fast so I wouldn't mind using it. If I could get it to extract all of the files AND run it in my MATLAB script, I would be happy to use it. However, I don't know how to do either of those things at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found in MATLAB is the following function, where "id" is the name of the ID TXT file, "sdfs" is the SDF database, and "sdf_name" is the name of the new SDF file with the molecules extracted by ID:

```
function write_sdf(id, sdfs, sdf_name)
% Open the text file of ids.
fid = fopen(id);

% Convert the sdf file to a character array.
data = fileread(sdfs);

% For each id, get the portion of the sdf file corresponding
% to the molecule id.
while true
    mol_id = fgetl(fid);
    mol_full = '';

    % When we're at the end of the file, leave the loop.
    if mol_id == -1
        % We're done with the id file.
        fclose(fid);
        break;
    else
        mol_after = extractAfter(data, mol_id);
        mol_between = extractBefore(mol_after, '$$$$');
        mol_full = [char(mol_id) char(mol_between) '$$$$'];

        % Write the molecule to the sdf file.
        writelines(mol_full, sdf_name, WriteMode='append');
    end
 end

end
```

The problem with this solution is that it is VERY slow. If someone knows a faster way to do this please let me know! For now, I will be using this.